# Wordpress user roles/permissions

Tags: wordpress, user-roles

I have an admin user, and a contributor user.

Now when the contributor makes a new page it gets sent for approval by the administrator user. This is good , however i want this same ability but for when editing pages.

So if a contributor edits any page, the changes have to be approved by an administrator.

I do not know how to achieve this, I am using the User Role Editor Plugin but can still not get this to work.

Does any one know how i can implement this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities), a contributor is somebody who can write and manage their own posts but cannot publish them. I'm assuming your contributor is editing posts that have already been published? All you need to do is set them to draft and publish them again once you're happy with the edits.